# Update list of items in Blazor from another thread

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to get a list of items to update whenever a message is received from a message queue.

This only seems to work every *other* time a message is received though. It's definitely hitting the anonymous method inside the `SubscribeAsync` call each time, and I can't work out why it's not updating every time. I'm assuming it's related to that anonymous method being in a different thread. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
@page "/"
@inject IMessageQueueHelperFactory MessageQueueHelperFactory
@inject ILogger<Index> Logger
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
@using Newtonsoft.Json

<ul class="list-group">
    @foreach (var user in Users) {
        <li class="list-group-item">@user</li>
    }
</ul>

@code
{
    private List<string> Users { get; set; } = new List<string>();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        MessageQueueHelperFactory.Create(Queues.UserRegistration)
            .SubscribeAsync(async x =>
            {
                var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserRegistrationData>(x);
                Users.Add(user.Username);
                await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
            });

        base.OnInitialized();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to add a call to StateHasChanged?

Comment: Do you have the code in a repo, everyone can look at? At initial glance, try using the OnInitializedAsync method instead.

Comment: Hm, just a thought here.

I see you are using asynchronous code and by searching a bit within Microsoft's documentation, I came across the following: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-3.1#lifecycle-methods 

Which says that Blazor Server apps that prerender their content call OnInitializedAsync twice, once when the component is initially rendered statically as part of the page and second time when the browser establishes a connection back to the server.
Give it a glance and wrote back if you find something.

Comment: @vasilisdmr Ah, interesting! That certainly would explain what I'm seeing. I can't try it now, but I'll have a look first thing in the morning.

Comment: @ChananBraunstein Yes, my code snippet has a call to `StateHasChanged` already.

Comment: @HarryPooni It's not in a public repo I'm afraid. If I have no luck with vasilisdmr's suggestion, I'll see if I can get a repro case pushed to Github.

Comment: Your code looks largely Ok. The answer will probably be in what's happening in  MessageQueueHelperFactory.  The Async in SubscribeAsync suggests it may be do too much on the main thread. Do you have a non-async version?

Comment: @vasilisdmr That was it! :) I've switched over to using the `OnAfterRenderAsync` event when the `firstRender` parameter is true, and this works as expected. If you make this an answer, I can mark it as the correct answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Nice to hear that! Glad that we found out the solution!
I will add it as an answer. @Dan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Microsoft's documentation, I came across this article: 
[Component initialization methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-3.1#component-initialization-methods)

It says that:

> Blazor Server apps that prerender their content call OnInitializedAsync twice
>
> - Once when the component is initially rendered statically as part of
>     the page.
> - A second time when the browser establishes a connection back to the
>     server.

So, I guess if you use [OnAfterRenderAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-3.1#after-parameters-are-set) with the first parameter set to true will solve your problem